# Why define a function inside a decorator?

Tags: python, python-decorators

Why is it a practice to define a new function inside a decorator as the wrapper function below:

```
def not_during_the_night(func):
    def wrapper():
        if 7 <= datetime.now().hour < 22:
            return func
        else:
            pass  # Hush, the neighbours are asleep
    return wrapper
```

Instead of just doing something like?:

```
def not_during_the_night(func):
    if 7 <= datetime.now().hour < 22:
        return func
     else:
        pass  # Hush, the neighbours are asleep
```

Isn't the final result the same? Also, if we need to add some functionality we can do that as well so I really don't get why decorators are written like this but there must be a good reason for it. `:)`

EDIT: I accidentally left brackets inside the first case, the question was supposed to be like this

Comment: If you try the second thing, you'll see what the problems are. The result is *not* the same if: 1. the wrapped function is called more than once; or 2. you wrap the function at night.

Comment: Because a decorator is nothing more than syntactic sugar for calling a function that turns a function. In other words, `@not_during_the_night`, follwed by `def somefunc(…):`, is equivalent to putting `somefunc = not_during_the_night(somefunc)` following the definition of `somefunc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of a decorator is to return a function you can call as needed, with enhanced functionality according to the decorator's purpose.

What you suggest will fail in use.  First of all, if I instantiate this during the night, your proposal will return `None`, and my calling program will crash, even if I call the function at noon.

More generally, your proposal freezes the functionality based on time of instantiation, rather than when my use case calls the function.

Answer (score 1):

It won't be the same result, in the first example with a wrapper the time condition will be checked each time you call the decorated function. And in the second example, the time condition will be checked just once at the time you apply the decorator to a function.